# Understanding recursion in streams

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand recursion in streams, it is confusing. My code is this

```
  val bigIntFromStream : Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: bigIntFromStream.zip(bigIntFromStream.tail).map{x =>
    println(s"stream = ${bigIntFromStream} + stream.tail = ${bigIntFromStream.tail} + zipped value = ${bigIntFromStream.zip(bigIntFromStream.tail)}")
    println(s"Calculating value for ${x}, {x._1} = ${x._1}, {x._2} = ${x._2}")
    x._1 + x._2}
```

The output for the code is this

```
0 1 stream = Stream(0, 1, ?) + stream.tail = Stream(1, ?) + zipped value = Stream((0,1), ?)

Calculating value for (0,1), {x._1} = 0, {x._2} = 1
1 stream = Stream(0, 1, 1, ?) + stream.tail = Stream(1, 1, ?) + zipped value = Stream((0,1), ?)

Calculating value for (1,1), {x._1} = 1, {x._2} = 1
2 stream = Stream(0, 1, 1, 2, ?) + stream.tail = Stream(1, 1, 2, ?) + zipped value = Stream((0,1), ?)

Calculating value for (1,2), {x._1} = 1, {x._2} = 2
3 stream = Stream(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ?) + stream.tail = Stream(1, 1, 2, 3, ?) + zipped value = Stream((0,1), ?)

Calculating value for (2,3), {x._1} = 2, {x._2} = 3
5 stream = Stream(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ?) + stream.tail = Stream(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, ?) + zipped value = Stream((0,1), ?)

Calculating value for (3,5), {x._1} = 3, {x._2} = 5
```

My question is how does x get the last value of the zip between the actual value and it's tail? Please tell me if I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a `Stream` starts out as a single element with a promise to get more if needed. That's the case even if all the elements are fully defined.

```
val ns = Stream(1,2,3,4,5)
//ns: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

And a collection zipped with its own tail effectively pairs each element with its neighbor.

```
val paired = ns zip ns.tail
//paired: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((1,2), ?)
// The rest are (2,3), (3,4) and (4,5), but they haven't been realized yet.
```

Also, when you index a `Stream` it is a linear operation. In other words, if you want `paired(3)` the code will step through ("realize") `paired(0)`, and then `paired(1)`, then `paired(2)`, and finally `paired(3)`.

So the `Stream` you've posted is essentially:

```
// This is concept, not code.
Stream(a=0, b=1, c=a+b, d=b+c, e=c+d, ...)
```

Notice that at each index, after the first two, the new element is the sum of 2 previous elements, but those previous elements had to be realized before we could get here, so that's OK. And this is a, potentially, infinite progression, but a `Stream` only calculates (realizes) an element on request so the elements that aren't requested don't yet exist so they don't take up any memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
object Test extends App {
  var bigIntFromStream : Stream[BigInt] = Stream(0,1)

  def addItems(n: Int)(x: Stream[BigInt]): Unit = {
    if(n > 0){
      val lastIndex: Int = bigIntFromStream.indices.last
      bigIntFromStream ++= Stream(bigIntFromStream(lastIndex - 1) + bigIntFromStream(lastIndex))
      addItems(n-1)(bigIntFromStream)
    }
  }

  addItems(10)(bigIntFromStream)

  println(bigIntFromStream.mkString(","))
}
```